# Postgresql: Partitioning a table for values in SELECT

Tags: postgresql, table-partitioning

I want to use PostgreSQL's declarative table partitioning on a column with UUID values. I want it partitioned by values that are returned by a SELECT.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    type_id uuid NOT NULL,
    -- other columns
    PRIMARY KEY (id, type_id)
) PARTITION BY LIST (type_id);

CREATE TABLE foo_1 PARTITION OF foo
    FOR VALUES IN (SELECT id FROM type_ids WHERE type_name = 'type1');
CREATE TABLE foo_2 PARTITION OF foo
    FOR VALUES IN (SELECT id FROM type_ids WHERE type_name = 'type2');
```

I don't want to use specific UUIDs in `FOR VALUES IN ('uuid')`, since the UUIDs may differ by environment (dev, qa, prod). However, the `SELECT` syntax doesn't seem to be accepted by Postgres. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not? And any alternatives?

Comment: Why not? Because nobody implemented it. Probably because it simply doesn't make sense. What if the rows from `type_ids` where deleted after you create the partitions? Or suddenly new types appear with additional UUIDs?

Comment: Oh, and I don't want it to be dynamically evaluated. I just wanted the SELECT to be evaluated at the table creation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I just wanted the SELECT to be evaluated at the table creation time*

You should have made that clear in the question, not in a comment.

In that case - if this is a one time thing, you can use dynamic SQL, e.g. wrapped into a procedure

```
create procedure create_partition(p_part_name text, p_type_name text)
as
$$
declare
  l_sql text;
  l_id uuid;
begin
  select id
    into l_id
  from type_ids
  where type_name = p_type_name;

  l_sql := format('CREATE TABLE %I PARTITION OF foo FOR VALUES IN (%L)', p_part_name, l_id);
  execute l_sql;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then you can do:

```
call create_partition('foo_1', 'type1');
call create_partition('foo_2', 'type2');
```